# Check If Answer is Correct by Similarity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, ai

I am new to data science and machine learning.

Let's say that I have a question, and some correct answers for that question (for example, 10 correct answers). Is there a way to get a new answer as input, and "calculate" whether it is right? If you can recommend some readings, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

That problem is commonly called [question answering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering). It sounds like the particular framing is [answer selection](https://paperswithcode.com/task/answer-selection/latest) which can be framed as [learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank).

A recent, revelvant paper is [Learning to Rank Question-Answer Pairs using Hierarchical Recurrent Encoder with Latent Topic Clustering](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/learning-to-rank-question-answer-pairs-using) by Yoon et al.